# Nvidia 9.2 CUDA toolkit nvcc install error

Tags: nvidia, nvcc

I am trying to install the CUDA toolkit on Ubuntu 16.04 with

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

and keep getting the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-9-2 (>= 9.2.148) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

any help?

Comment: This is a Ubuntu package management question rather than any specifically related to CUDA programming and would be far better asked as askubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-runtime-9-2
sudo apt-get install cuda-9-2
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Option 2:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install cuda
```